# Angularjs - Spring MVC Rest : how to handle exceptions

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am developping an single page app with angularjs and Spring Mcv Rest.
I am calling my service (mail sending with javax mail) like that in Angularjs : `SendProformaFax.get({idCommande:$scope.commande.id})`

And on server side my service :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendProformaFax/{idCommande}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void imprimeProforma(@PathVariable String idCommande) {
        Commande commande = commandeRepository.findOne(new Long(idCommande));
        List<Vente> ventes = venteRepository.findAllByCommande(commande);
        blService.sendProformaFax(ventes);
   }
```

I would like to display a message when the function sendProformaFax throws a MessagingException.

I don't know how to return this exception in my RestController and how to catch it in Angularjs.

If anyone can help me on this...
Thanks.

EDIT : 
On server side I am doing this :

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ErrorView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
        // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
        // at the start of this post.
        // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
            throw e;

        // Otherwise setup and send the user to a default error-view.
        ErrorView mav = new ErrorView();
        mav.setException(e.getMessage());
        mav.setUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
        mav.setMessage("Veuillez contacter le support informatique.");
        return mav;
    }
```

On Angularjs side I am doing this

```
CreateFichierCiel.get({params:param}, function (response) {
                $scope.infoMessage = "La génération du fichier CIEL est terminée."
                $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
                $("#messageModal").modal('show');
                $scope.find();
            }, function (reason) {
                $("#errorModal").modal('show');
            })
```

But 'reason' object is like this :

> config: Object data: Object error: "Internal Server Error" exception:
>   "java.lang.NullPointerException" message: "No message available" path:
>   "/api/createFichierCiel/15-00005" status: 500 timestamp: 1438430232307
>   proto: Object headers: function (name) { status: 500 statusText:
>   "Internal Server Error" proto: Object

So I am not getting the ErrorView class sent from the server.
If anyone can see where I am wrong here...

Thanks

Comment: look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295184/spring-mvc-rest-service-controller-with-error-handling-done-right

Comment: Which version of Spring you are using?

Comment: <swagger-springmvc.version>0.8.8</swagger-springmvc.version>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `ExceptionHandler` for `MessagingException` and set `HTTPStatus` to indicate that response has an error (egz. `BAD_REQUEST`)

```
@ExceptionHandler(MessagingException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorView handleMessagingException(MessagingException ex) {
    // do something with exception and return view
}
```

In AngularJS you can catch it from resource service like this:

```
MessagingService.get({idCommande: 1}, function (data) {
// this is success
}, function (reason) {
// this is failure, you can check if this is a BAD_REQUEST and parse response from exception handler
};
```

It almost the same when you use `$http`.

Comment: Thanks, I am a bit confused: what is ErrorView, a custom class or a Spring class?

Comment: @user1260928 Your custom class. You can return some description what failed etc. in response object like ErrorView (just my example).

Comment: can you explain the angularjs side a little bit more? I just don't understand what is MessagingService, where should you add it and basically what is get({idCommande: 1} ?

Comment: @Shilan MessagingService is like I wrote an [angular resource service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer by **kTT**, starting with `Spring 4` you can wrap your `@ExceptionHandler` method in a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` so that you will have the same message for the same type of exception across the whole application. More you can look [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#global-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

That is how I did it, we are using spring mvc and angularjs in our project.
I have this controllerAdvice class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

@ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> rulesForCustomerNotFound(HttpServletRequest req, ServiceException e) 
{
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
    error.portalErrorCode = e.getExceptionCode(); 
    error.message = e.getMessage();
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

class ErrorResponse {
   public int portalErrorCode;
   public String message;
}
```

and then in restful controller where ServiceException is a customized runnable exception:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping("/getControls/{entity}")
public List<Control> getControls(@PathVariable(value="entity") String entity) throws ServiceException {
    List<Control> controls = ImmutableList.of();
     try {
        controls = dao.selectControls(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("getting list of controls encountered an error ", e);
        throw new ServiceException(50, "getting list of controls encountered an error.");
    }
     return controls;
}
```

in my app.js file in angularjs I use

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        'response': function (response) {
            //Will only be called for HTTP up to 300
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 0) {
                alert('There is a problem connecting to the server. Is the server probably down?!');
            }
            else {
                $location.url('/error').search({rejection: rejection});
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
}])
```

and in a error.controller.js

```
function init() {       
    ctrl.rejection = $location.search().rejection; 
    ctrl.portalErrorCode = ctrl.rejection.data.portalErrorCode;
    ctrl.errorMessage = ctrl.rejection.data.message;
    $log.info('An error occured while trying to make an ajax call' + ctrl.errorMessage + ': ' + ctrl.portalErrorCode);
}
```

and of course in error.tpl.html

```
            <h2>
               {{ctrl.rejection.status}} {{ctrl.rejection.statusText}}
            </h2>
            <h3 class="error-details">
                Sorry, an error has occurred!
            </h3>
            <h3 class="error-details">
                {{ctrl.errorMessage}}
            </h3>
```