# Spring MVC: let RestController serialize different classes to JSON

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Just for the sake of an example let's assume I want to create a REST endpoint which returns the message of the day (motd). The incoming parameter is the day represented by a number, the outcome is JSON which contains the day and the message.

```
public class Motd {
  int day;
  String message;
  ...
}
```

This gets translated into ...

```
{ 
  "day": 1,
  "message": "whatever you want to say here"
}
```

... and is returned by this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/motd", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Motd> getMotd(@RequestParam(value = "day") int day {
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<Motd>(motd, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This works fine as long everything is ok but my intention is to return both a http status code and a JSON explaining the reason for any errors that might occur:

```
...
if( day > 365 ) {
    Status error = new Status( "failed", "can't go beyond 365 days" );
    return new ResponseEntity<Status>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
...
```

But this conflicts with the `ResponseEntity<Motd>` defined earlier. The only solution I know so far is to define `ResponseEntity<String>` and serialize the JSON on my own.
Are there any alternatives / more elegant alternatives which allow Spring return "varying" classes ?

The emphasis of my question is not on error handling, I was shown some clever ways to do this [based on exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295184/spring-mvc-rest-service-controller-with-error-handling-done-right) for example. And if possible I want to avoid deriving all possible returned classes from a common base class.

My code is based on Spring Boot 1.3 RC1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Rest Service Controller with Error Handling done right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295184/spring-mvc-rest-service-controller-with-error-handling-done-right)

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thanks for your input. Although the links shows some clever ways of dealing with errors it does not show ways to return different types of classes / json-ified objects besides deriving from a common class. So I think this does not handle my question completely. I will edit my question in order to describe better what I want to avoid

Comment: Any reason for not using ResponseEntity<Object>, or ResponseEntity<SomeCommonInterface>?

Comment: @ZoranRegvart Both would be my last resort but `ResponseEntity<Object>` is _very_ generic and `ResponseEntity<SomeCommonInterface>` can be difficult because I don't have access to all classes that might be returned (please remember that the above is just a simplified example)

Comment: @Marged And in a statically typed language such as Java, do you think you have an abundance of alternatives? Your method must return a type for every situation you envision in the body of the method, at least that's your goal, my suggestion is to live with that choice.

Comment: @ZoranRegvart One alternative would be enough, I don't need abundance ;-) I just want to get some input (like yours) because perhaps there are alternatives I have not thought off. Those that came to my mind so far didn't enchant me

Comment: @Marged Well, good luck finding them

Comment: To avoid this problem you could create a common wrapper object, e.g. [the Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper). Normally it has a result field. If something goes wrong there's an error field. Works well if you need to add pagination at some point too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `ResponseEntity`, Spring MVC does not care about the parameterized return type, it cares only about the value.

You can simply provide

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getMotd(@RequestParam(value = "day") int day {
```

Spring MVC's `HttpEntityMethodProcessor`, which handles values returned by your handler methods that are of type `ResponseEntity`, will retrieve the `body` of the `ResponseEntity` and delegate writing to the response to an appropriate `HttpMessageConverter`.

The same process will happen for an `Motd` value as it will for a `Status` value.