# How error is captured in orbeon from Java code?

Tags: java, orbeon

I have this configuration :

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-to-myservice.*.*">
     set-data-status(status="safe")
     then send( uri="http://localhost:80/myservice",content="xml",   replace="none")
     then success-message(message="Saved Successfully")
     recover error-message(message="Save Failed")
</property>
```

*myservice* gets called and lets say I have like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myservice", method = {RequestMethod.POST},
  produces = XML_CONTENT_TYPE)
@ResponseBody
  public String myservice(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException {

try {
  //Some logic
} catch (Exception e) {
  return "fail";
}
return "success";
}
```

I get `Saved Successfully` message even if myService throws exception.

How can I display `Save Failed` incase of exceptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Rest Service Controller with Error Handling done right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295184/spring-mvc-rest-service-controller-with-error-handling-done-right)

Comment: You're swallowing the exception and return a normal String instead ... how should the calling method know that there was a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in a comment, instead of swallowing the exception and return the string "fail", you want your service to return an HTTP error code when error happens. I am not familiar with framework you're using to write this service, but this might just happen out of the box if you let your method throw an exception in case of error.